# How to set an object in story file?

Tags: java, jbehave

I use JBehave to test my code.

Here is the code snippet from the story

```
Scenario: I pass the correct data to calculator
When the given data is ABC
Then the result entity should look like
|a|100|
|b|200|
```

Here is my entity class.

```
class ResultEntity {
    private int a;
    private int b;
    // getter/setters
}
```

And Then method

```
@Then("the result entity should look like $")
public void thenTheResultEntityShouldLookLike(ResultEntity resultEntity) {
    // some code
}
```

How can I set in the `*.story` file my result entity?

Comment: just to clarify you want to read a param in the then statement and use it to set your object?

Comment: I use that object to compare it with calculated object in when statement.

Answer (score 0):

The story should maybe look like this

```
Scenario: I pass the correct data to calculator
When the given data is <entity>
Then the result entity should look like <value>
Examples:
|entity|value|
|a|100|
|b|200|
```

The "Then" method should maybe look like this

```
@Then("the result entity should look like <entity>")
public void thenTheResultEntityShouldLookLike(@Named("entity") ResultEntity resultEntity) {
    // some code
}
```